# Insert bulk data into tables that are in a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I have a .NET App connected to a Postgres DB using Npgsql and I am trying to import data into two tables, say Users and Todos. A user has many todos. The User table has an `id` column that is automatically set by the DB, and the Todos table has a foreign key to the Users table called `user_id`.

Now, I know how to insert Users, and I know how to insert Todos, but I do not know how to set the `user_id` for those Todos since the `id` column from User is only known after the users are inserted into the DB. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you are importing and which tool you are using. If you are using raw INSERT statements, PostgreSQL has a RETURNING clause which will send you back the ID of the inserted statements ([see the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)).

If you are using binary COPY (which is the most efficient way to bulk-import data), there's no such option. This case, one good way is to "allocate" all the ids in one go, by incrementing the sequence backing the ID column, and then sending the IDs when you're importing. This means the database is longer generating those IDs - you're sending them explicitly like any other field.

In practical terms, say you have 100 users (and any number of todos). You can do one call to `setval` to increment the sequence by 100, and then you can import your users, explicitly setting their IDs to those 100 values. This allows you to also specify the user IDs on the todos. However, if you do this, be mindful of concurrency issues if someone else modifies the sequence at the same time.